# How to update varbinary(max) column with path stored in varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, varbinarymax

I currently have a varchar(255) column that stores the path to a small image file.  I want to try to load the file into a new column of type varbinary(max), but don't know how to write a stored procedure to do such.  Something like such

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET image = "file located in field imagePath"
```

I know that makes no sense because I don't have a where clause, but what would I put in it's place??

Comment: So you have the path in one table and your question is you want to use that path and take the file and load that file into a column which is present in another table.Do I make sense?

Comment: Yes I have the file paths in one field and I want to load the file into another field then eventually delete the first field.  Switching from images stored in the filesystem to stored in a varbinary(max) field.  This is on SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is not well suited to accessing the file system, but this task would not be difficult to accomplish in a C#/VB.NET program.

EDIT: Tim Lehner's OPENROWSET solution is ideal if you are on SQL 2005 or later.

Comment: SQLCLR could be used here. I don't have time to look up the all the pieces to get it working myself.

Comment: @Jeremy Pridemore, you could look [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2349/read-and-write-binary-files-with-the-sql-server-clr/).

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just writing a small C# application that reads the urls from the database and does a select into query.  Doing 100,000+ updates vs 100,000+ inserts was WAY slower.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to create a stored procedure to do this. I've used the procs outlined in here to good effect:

[Reading and Writing Files in SQL Server using T-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/)

My purposes only included text, but binary is mentioned.

Depending upon your version of SQL Server, you might try [openrowset](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/), or as @Jeremy Pridemore mentions, you may be able to [use the CLR](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2349/read-and-write-binary-files-with-the-sql-server-clr/).

**UPDATE**

This code may help you if you're using SQL2005 or above:

```
declare @MyFile varbinary(max)
select @MyFile = bulkcolumn 
from openrowset (bulk 'C:\SomeFolder\SomeImage.jpg', single_blob) myfile
select @MyFile
```